# Which library contains pulseaudio pa_simple_new function

Tags: java-native-interface, shared-libraries, pulseaudio

I am writing a java application. It is an mp3 player. I want to use the pulseaudio server because my bluetooth speaker is accessible with pulseaudio.

I have written a shared library using the simple pulseaudio interface.

Now i get the error

/home/rainer/NetBeansProjects/audioserver/src/main/native/audioserver.so: undefined symbol: pa_simple_new

which library i have to add to my java program to get access to the symbol pa_simple_new ?

Answer (score 2):

After searching around, i found the library libpulse-simple.so contains the functions. There were shown when executing

```
nm -D libpulse-simple.so
```

I wasn't able to call the functions directly, because i call this functions in a JNI environment.

I had to use the functions dlopen and dlsym for accessing the functions:

```
void* h = dlopen("libpulse-simple.so", RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_GLOBAL);
```

and

```
  ptr_pa_simple_new = (pa_simple* (*)(const char *,const char *,pa_stream_direction_t,const char *,const char *,const pa_sample_spec *,const pa_channel_map *,const pa_buffer_attr *,int *))dlsym(h,"pa_simple_new");
  ptr_pa_simple_free = (void (*)(pa_simple *))dlsym(h,"pa_simple_free");
  ptr_pa_simple_write = (int (*)(pa_simple *, const void *, size_t, int *))dlsym(h,"pa_simple_write");
```